# Keep getting exception on alter table hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I keep getting an exception during startup where `alter` table doesn't seem to work during application start up. The exception is too generic to find out the root cause. Below is the exception. How can I fix this.

```
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
        alter table employee_name 
           add constraint FKddd5d7fpwoci6s9sttbbokh3c 
           foreign key (employee_id) 
           references employee_salary)data (salary_id)" via JDBC Statement
            at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java
    :67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar!/:5.4.25.Final]
            at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:439) [hibernat
te-core-5.4.25.Final.jar!/:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:423) [hibern
ate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar!/:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:374) [hib
ernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar!/:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166) [hibern
ate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar!/:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135) [hibernate-c
ore-5.4.25.Final.jar!/:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121) [hibernate-c
ore-5.4.25.Final.jar!/:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementTool
Coordinator.java:156) [hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar!/:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.ja
va:73) [hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar!/:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:316) [hibernate-core-5.4.25.Fin
al.jar!/:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:469) [hiberna
te-core-5.4.25.Final.jar!/:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.ja
va:1259) [hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar!/:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFac
tory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) [spring-orm-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(Loca
lContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEnt
ityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) [spring-orm-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFac
toryBean.java:396) [spring-orm-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEnti
tyManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractA
utowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847) [spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAuto
wireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) [spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowi
reCapableBeanFactory.java:609) [spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowire
CapableBeanFactory.java:531) [spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.jav
a:335) [spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBean
Registry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) [s
pring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) [spr
ing-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionVal
ueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefini
tionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorRes
olver.java:693) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorR
esolver.java:510) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMeth
od(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) [spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(Abstract
AutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1179) [spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowi
reCapableBeanFactory.java:571) [spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowire
CapableBeanFactory.java:531) [spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionVal
ueResolver.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefini
tionValueResolver.java:134) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(Abstrac
tAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1691) [spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowi
reCapableBeanFactory.java:1436) [spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowi
reCapableBeanFactory.java:608) [spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowire
CapableBeanFactory.java:531) [spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.jav
a:335) [spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBean
Registry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) [s
pring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) [spr
ing-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java
:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListable
BeanFactory.java:1367) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBe
anFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.
inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spri
```

Below are my properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Comment: What MySQL version do you use?

Comment: And could you please show full stack trace.

Comment: updated the question. Mysql version is 8.0.22

Comment: sorry its actually 8.0.23